Help with "delta dirac" integral
Let $f_0(x)$ be a positive, symmetric and bounded function and $c > 0$ some constant. I came across
the following integral:
$$ I = \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \frac{d}{dx} \left[\text{sign}( |x| -c  )\right] f_0(x) dx $$
Using delta "functions" freely ,I tried: $ \frac{d}{dy} \text{sign}( y ) "= 2\delta(y)" $  giving:
$$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 2 \delta\left( |x| -c  \right) \times \frac{x}{|x|} \times f_0(x)  dx $$
Now the delta in the integrand are two delta peaks centered at $c$ and $-c$ , and the integral can be split (?):
$$ I = I_{+c} + I_{-c} = 2 \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(x-c) \frac{x}{|x|}  f_0(x)dx + 2 \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(x+c) \frac{x}{|x|}  f_0(x)dx  $$
$$ = 2 f_0(c) - 2 f_0(c) = 0 $$
(where the symmetry of $f_0$ was used)
The answer is supposed to be $4f_0(c)$, what am I missing here ?

Normally the integral is defined by partial integration $$-\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f'(x) \text{sgn}(| x| -c) , dx$$ over f' yielding dirctly 2 f(c)-2f(-c) by the fact, that the Sign function  is +1 except for $x\in (-c,c)$

Using the representation $$g(x)=\text{sgn}(|x|-c)=1-2, \theta(c+x)+2, \theta(x-c)$$ leads to $$g'(x)=2, \delta(x-c)-2, \delta(c+x)$$ and $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g'(x), f_0(x) , dx=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (2, \delta(x-c)-2, \delta(c+x)), f_0(x) , dx=2, f_0(c)-2, f_0(-c)$$ which is consistent with the answer assuming $f_0(c)$ is an odd function where $f_0(-c)=-f_0(c)$, but this is inconsistent with $f_0(x)$ being a positive function.

Your result is correct. As a check, notice that $\text{sign}(|x|-c)$ is an even function of $x$, hence its derivative is odd, so the integrand of $I$ is also odd if $f_0(x)$ is even.

$\displaystyle\left.\delta\left(\left\vert x\right\vert - c\right)\right\vert_{c\ >\ 0} = \delta\left(x + c\right) + \delta\left(x - c\right)$
